# How do I extract the lower/upper triangle of a non-square numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

So basically I have an array **subslope** consisting of the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

slp = 1501.66*(np.ones((1000,1000), dtype=np.float32))
vsub = 2000*(np.ones((1000,1000), dtype=np.float32))

slope = np.triu(slp)
slope2 = np.tril(vsub, k=-1)
subslope = slope + slope2
```

This is the visual representation:

[image]

You can see the diagonal separating two parts of the array, the upper part has values of 1501.66 and 2000 below the diagonal. However, when I change the dimensions such that the number of columns is significantly larger than the number of rows like this:

```
slp = 1501.66*(np.ones((1000,2000), dtype=np.float32))
vsub = 2000*(np.ones((1000,2000), dtype=np.float32))
```

We get the following:

[image]

What I want is the diagonal to run from the top corner of the array to the bottom corner like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How will you "round" the indices. Up, down, round?

Comment: I would like to round up

Comment: Look at `np.tri` and `np.triu`to see how they derive the indices.  Maybe you can adapt those to work as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate your array, with *nR* rows and *nC* columns, filled:

- at the diagonal with *valDiag*,
- over the diagonal with *valUpper*,
- below the diagonal with *valLower*,

you can use the following function:

```
def genDiag(nR, nC, valUpper, valDiag, valLower):
    slope = nC / nR
    tbl = np.full((nR, nC), valDiag, dtype=float)
    for r in range(nR):
        tbl[r, 0 : int(round(slope * r, 0))] = valLower
        tbl[r, int(round(slope * (r + 1), 0)) : nC] = valUpper
    return tbl
```

To test it, on smaller numbers, run:

```
res = genDiag(8, 14, 15.1, 0, 20.2)
print(res)
```

The result is:

```
[[ 0.   0.  15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1]
 [20.2 20.2  0.   0.  15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1]
 [20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2  0.  15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1]
 [20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2  0.   0.  15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1]
 [20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2  0.   0.  15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1]
 [20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2  0.  15.1 15.1 15.1 15.1]
 [20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2  0.   0.  15.1 15.1]
 [20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2  0.   0. ]]
```

If you want this table without separate filling for the diagonal,
first make up your mind whether the diagonal elements are to be filled
with "upper" or "lower" value, then pass the selected value as *valDiag*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to create a boolean mask:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shape = (1000, 2000)
i,j = np.indices(shape)
m = np.ceil(i <= j*shape[0]/shape[1]).astype(bool)

subslope = np.empty(shape, np.float32)
subslope[m] = 1501.66
subslope[~m] = 2000

plt.imshow(subslope)
```

[image]